# Can I access to one params from scope?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have this code in my route file , So I need to get the param ':locale' in the scope

```
 scope '/:locale', :locale => /it|en|es/ do
     # How I can access value of :locale here ?
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://dhampik.com/blog/rails-routes-tricks-with-locales) blog explains quite well what you are trying to achieve.

The idea is that you can use `I18n.available_locales` and `I18n.default_locale` to do pretty much everything that you want.

```
# resources
scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  resources :posts
end

# default url
root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}", status: 302), as: :redirected_root

# constraint to redirect when no valid locale is specified
get "/*path", to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302), 
  constraints: {path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/}, format: false
```

And to answer your question, here's how you can use the current locale

```
scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  root to: redirect("/%{locale}/posts", status: 302)
end
```